# Instrumental Variable and "Exclusivity"

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect, dag, causal-diagram

In the following DAG:

[image]

Can I use IV1 as an instrument for exposure?

In the [this video](https://youtu.be/9xGeCGRvVgE?t=266) at 4:26 the teacher explains a principle of "exclusivity" for instrumental variables.

> Cutoff causes outcome **only through** program

I wonder whether I got that concept right

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IV1` as an instrument, if you also adjust for `Covariate`, with some reservations.  Since you are conditioning on `Covariate`, there is no open confounding path from `IV1` to `Outcome` and the coefficient of `IV1` in the regression `Outcome~IV1+Covariate` estimates the part of the effect of `IV1` acting via `Exposure`.   A regression of `Exposure` on `IV1` estimates the effect of `IV1` on `Exposure`,and the ratio gives the effect of `Exposure` on `Outcome`.

Among the reservations: in general, there will be an interaction between `Covariate` and `Exposure` so there's no such thing as **the** effect of `Exposure` there to be estimated. Also, any measurement error in `Covariate` will mean that adjusting for `Covariate` isn't completely effective in blocking that path and the exclusion restriction will be violated.

There's an example like this on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation#Selecting_suitable_instruments), which also shows how the answer varies with changes in the causal graph.

Comment: "A regression of Exposure on IV1 estimates the effect of IV1 on Exposure, and the ratio gives the effect of Exposure on Outcome." Shouldn't it be a regression of Exposure on IV1 and covariate, instead of just on IV1?

Comment: I don't think so.  According to the graph, there's no confounding in the regression of exposure on IV1, just in the regression of outcome on IV1.